# My computer is totally messed up, how can I reset it?

Tags: windows, reset, windows-installation

Ever since I formatted a partition (which was separate from all my files) to allow OS X to install on it (which never even worked) it has created nothing but problems.  I have like 3 windows.old files, when I re-installed windows and tried moving all the files with the cmd (guide on microsoft.com) it only moved shortcuts that don't work and made my computer extremely slow.  Also all my drivers won't install, only a few of them.  Is there a way I can just reset it to the state I received it?  Everything in one partition, all the drivers, NO old files, and a repaired OS selection screen (I have a dual boot with Ubuntu, which I don't even have the option to boot.)

I have a manufactured refurbished Gateway NV55S09u.

Comment: You cannot install OS X on a Gateway computer.  Question on how to do this are not on topic for this website.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you tried to build a Hackintosh but failed. If you're willing to lose all your data, the way to reinstall clean is... well, you just kind of *do it*. There are a bunch of ways:

1. Did your machine come with a Gateway recovery CD? It should give you the option to restore to factory... if not, it sucks :)
2. Do you have a Windows install CD (NOT an Upgrade CD)? Put in the CD, use the tool during installation to delete all your partitions, and create your desired partition setup from scratch.
3. Download and burn a Linux live CD (an almost-uncountable number of them exist; you can try [SystemRescueCD](http://sysresccd.org) or [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org) for starters) and use Disk Utility or Gparted to delete all your partitions. You can do this if you have a spare CD-RW/DVD-RW regardless of what software is already on your PC, at no charge other than the cost of burning the disc.

If you want to keep your personal files, you will need to attach another storage device (most conveniently, a USB storage device like a flash drive or USB hard drive) and copy off the files from your Windows partition that you can't afford to lose. Then proceed with one of the above options.

And, sorry to say, if these options weren't blindingly obvious to you before asking this question, you *probably* should not have been messing around with a Hackintosh. Lesson learned, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean install, and make sure you know what you want to do with your PC. For the time being, install Windows and if you want to try Linux or Hackintosh use a virtual machine.

However, if you want to go for further experimentation, I would suggest to go for the bootloader, and mess with it further using a USB drive.